# SoundPool and MediaPlayer volume correspondence problem

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-6.0-marshmallow, soundpool

In in Alcatel POP 4+ with Android 6.0.1, I have very low volume in SoundPool sounds and high volume in MediaPlayer sounds without changing volume, just playing the sounds. In other devices and emulators it works perfectly.

I'm playing SFX's with sound pool using this:

```
soundPool.play(soundID[sound], 1, 1, 0, loop, 1);
```

And music using this:

```
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

As you can see I'm not specifying the volume, but in Alcatel POP 4+ with Android 6.0.1, the volume of the SFX (SoundPool) is super low.

I tried specifying volume 1 for `MediaPlayer` with `mPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);` but the result is the same.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both the `MediaPlayer` and the `SoundPool` play on the same audio stream. This is done by setting `int streamType` below Android 5 and `AudioAttributes` on Android 5+.

`streamType` is going to be one of the [stream constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC) in `AudioManager`, for example `STREAM_MUSIC`.

Use the [builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.Builder) to construct `AudioAttributes` object. You no longer deal with stream types directly. Android will assign your player a stream based on what you pass in `setUsage` and `setContentType`, for example

```
new AudioAttributes.Builder()
         .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
         .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
         .build()
```

For `SoundPool` before Lollilop use the now-deprecated [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#SoundPool(int,%20int,%20int)):

```
new SoundPool(maxStreams, streamType, 0)
```

For `SoundPool` after Lollipop use its [builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)):

```
new SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(maxStreams)
        .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
        .build()
```

For `MediaPlayer` before Lollipop call [`setAudioStreamType(int streamType)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)) before `prepare`.

For `MediaPlayer` after Lollipop call [`setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)) before `prepare`.

---

Typically music plays on `STREAM_MEDIA`, phone call rings on `STREAM_RING`, alarm rings on `STREAM_ALARM` and so on. Do what the user expects.

When nothing is playing the volume buttons control `STREAM_RING`. When there's anything using the `STREAM_MUSIC` the volume buttons control that. At least on my phone running Android 8. I believe things have changed in Android 9 or 10, I'm not sure.